# Keep .gitignore clean?

Tags: git

It makes sense to me that `.gitignore` should only include files that the project **has** to produce inside the source directory when you run some configuration or build step. All else that pertains to personal workflow should go into `.git/info/exclude`.

Let's say I'm starting a new project using, say, CMake so that there is never a need to generate any files in the source directory. Would it make sense to forbid the developers from using `.gitignore` at all?

I'm currently working on an older project where the developers are used to building inside the source directory. As a result, `.gitignore` is littered with all kinds of file types. It has happened to me a few times that I push something and it doesn't compile on somebody else's machine and the reason is that my source directory differs slightly from theirs due to some files that I didn't even know where there because `.gitignore` made them invisible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `.gitignore` can be overused, it is still an absolutely necessary tool. I've seen repositories that included everything including temporary build files because someone blindly did a `git add --all`. So how do various git exclude mechanisms fit into a development process?

- `.gitignore` is for project-specific excludes that are generated by the build process. For a CMake-based project, this would typically be a `build` directory and not much more. For a project with in-source builds, this would be any output files of the compilation process, e.g. `*.o` and some named executables.
- `.git/info/exclude` is for project-specific excludes that stem from your personal workflow. E.g. IDE configuration files. OTOH IDE configuration files should sometimes be under source control, especially if you've standardized your IDE across your team.
- `~/.gitignore` is for global excludes that stem from your personal workflow, e.g. editor swapfiles.

Sometimes you want to ignore most files of a kind while committing others. There isn't a single best solution here.

- Ignoring these files by default is possible. If you need to version-control one of these files, you can still add it explicitly. The danger is that you forget to add it, because `git status` won't show it.

  E.g. a project I work on generates `*.gcda` coverage files during its test cases. I generally want to ignore those. But the project is a coverage tool. So if a test case depends on a particular .gcda file, I would commit that file as an exception.
- Only ignoring specific output file patterns may be possible if you know a sufficiently specific name. E.g. I often do this to ignore packages and archives, like `/My-Project-v*.tar.gz`.
- If possible, using a separate build directory is probably best, because you can then ignore the build directory instead of concrete files.

The “it doesn't build on a different machine” problem cannot be solved by forbidding the use of a .gitignore – you would also have to outlaw other exclude mechanisms. The only way to solve this is by running automated tests each time you push. Setting up a Jenkins CI server is not terribly difficult, so go and do that.

Comment: So `.gitignore` can be used to prevent certain files from being comitted. I didn't even think of that!

Comment: @RaulLaasner No, .gitignore doesn't prevent files from being committed, it just excludes these files from `git status` and `git add --all` and similar commands. So even if you gitignore some files, you can explicitly commit them.

Comment: Yes, I should've said that it reduces the probability of some accidental commits. If your explicitly try to commit an ignored file, it at least asks for confirmation.

Comment: The first usage of gitignore is to avoid IDE specific files and folders to be commited. Temp files, logs, etc.

Comment: @amon: I think a more precise wording would be: .gitignore doesn't *prohibit* files from being committed, but it prevents them from being commited *accidentally*.

Comment: @amon Note that `.gitignore` has basically no effect on files that are already being tracked, so such files will show up in `git status` and such. For files that are not already being tracked, `.gitignore`d files require the `-f` flag to add them, and running `git add` with an untracked file in the middle of the argument list, and no `-f` flag will result in files before the untracked file being added, but not files after the untracked file.

Answer (score 3):

There are some clear reasons to have a `.gitgnore` file, and reasons to use some other exclusion mechanism.  The big difference between the exclusion mechanisms are ([reference](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)):

- `.gitignore` is checked in with the repository, so everyone has the same standard ignores
- `.git/info/exclude` exists for your single repository, but only your copy.
- `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global` exists for your entire profile.  That means you can have standard ignore files for all of your repositories.

My general guidelines are:

- Use `.gitignore` for projects with standard locations for your object files and finished binaries (i.e. MSBuild, Maven, Gradle, etc.)
- Use `.gitignore` for user specific project settings and generated config files when everyone is using the same IDE (i.e. Visual Studio projects)

Beyond that, use whatever you want.  I've found that mixing and matching Java IDE project files within a team that uses different IDEs is messy at best.  Most IDEs can generate the project from your Maven or Gradle project, so it's also wasteful.  I would consider using more global ignores for Java IDE files.

Any ignored files will not be considered when you do `git add .`.

Comment: Sure, I understand the overall guidelines. Where to draw the line though? For example, something like a `build` directory is pretty common, but not essential. Or should I exclude all object files that the build system can generate, even though it is usually not good practice to build in source? (+1 although the first answer is much the same.)

Comment: Honestly, if a Maven project always has a `target/` subdirectory, it really does need a `.gitignrore` entry or you risk someone else accidentally committing it.  The more subtle issues are with applications that use transforms to generate a standard file you expect to exist.  Non-standard stuff like that needs to be in your `.gitignore` or you will be detecting changes every time you build.  I rarely use the more global ignore options.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I switched `git add *` to `git add .`, since, in the former, the `*` will be expanded by the shell to all the files in the current directory before git sees it, so git will add those files even if they're in `.gitignore`. Feel free to roll back if I've made a mistake.

Comment: @8bittree, I wonder if there is a difference between Windows and Linux on this.  I'll chalk it up to learning something new.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Just did some testing and yep, in `cmd`, `*` adds everything in the current directory and below that isn't in `.gitignore`, but in `Bash`, `*` adds files until it encounters one that's in `.gitignore`, then it exits with an error and suggests using the `-f` flag to force add the file. If there were other files not yet added, they won't be processed. `*` in Bash will also ignore files starting with a `.`, although I think that can be changed in Bash's configuration. `git add .` and `git add "*"` seem to work the same in both Bash and cmd, but cmd does not like `git add '*'`.

Comment: Nice analysis.  In DOS cmd, double quotes are evaluated before everything else to include everything in the double quotes as one parameter.  I think single quotes is a valid file character, so it explains why there is that inconsistency.  https://kb.acronis.com/content/39790